# use mdfind to get list of matches with context?

Tags: terminal, spotlight

I want to search a folder of PDFs to find a particular string and get back a list of matches with a little of the surrounding context.

Using:

```
mdfind -onlyin ~/Dropbox/PDFs 'term' >> ~/Dropbox/searches/term.txt
```

I can get a list of files that contain a match, but I would like to see a little of the surrounding context so that I can tell a little bit more about the match. Ideally, with the filename prepended.

Something like:

```
~/Dropbox/PDFs/file1.pdf: here is the term you were searching
~/Dropbox/PDFs/file1.pdf: with term limits
~/Dropbox/PDFs/file2.pdf: the German term for a 
~/Dropbox/PDFs/file3.pdf: come up with a term for
etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mdfind` will only ever return filenames, it doesn't display any content, nor does it possess the ability to do so in looking at its man page.

So instead of using `mdutil`, I'd suggest using a `pdfgrep` instead. This tool is available via `brew`:

```
$ brew install pdfgrep
```

Once installed it works like this:

```
$ pwd
/Users/user1/pdf

$ pdfgrep website -r
./docs/misc/Web-Shells-rev2.pdf:Say I run into the following website:
./docs/misc/Web-Shells-rev2.pdf:home directory of a website for shared host web servers:
./docs/misc/Web-Shells-rev2.pdf:Many websites with upload capabilities still rely on client side validation (javascript). These are
./docs/misc/Web-Shells-rev2.pdf:reverse shell I've hosted the file on one of my websites. Just remember to rename the extension
./docs/misc/Web-Shells-rev2.pdf:the output file, we could overwrite IIS log files or even deface websites. Elements the user can
```

`pdfgrep` has the normal compliment of switches to do recursive `-r` as well as ignore case `-i`, or even do regex searches.

Comment: This is wrong. It should say, `mdfind` uses two query languages that are so poorly documented, almost everyone that tries searching files by content fails to get the query correct and concludes `mdfind` can't display content. This is correct in that you need a grep like tool so show content around the matched term. Spotlight does not expose that level of detail - only if the term was indexed in a specific file.